# How can I fix the graphics on GTA IV?

Tags: grand-theft-auto-iv

When I bought GTA IV from steam, the graphics were automaticly on the lowest. I of course, wanted to turn them up. It wouldn't work. It just said; "Your graphics settings are near, or exceeded the suggested resource limits for your system.... etc"
I have a decent gaming desktop computer, so graphics shouldn't be a problem. Please help D:[image]

Comment: ...perhaps you're at the limit?  What are your computer specs?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Since GTA IV was made a while ago, it gets confused when it has more than 2GB of VRAM available to it.
You have to open up the properties either in steam, or in the shortcut of the game and set launch options to `-nomemrestrict -norestrictions` in order to be able to change the graphics settings.

Comment: Can I marry you, random person on the internet?

Comment: Probably not in most countries, since I'm already married :P But you can upvote my answer if you want ;) No pressure.

Comment: Sure, magical internet creature

Comment: Does this work for any old steam game?

Comment: You can try, but these launch options have to be implemented in the game by the developers, so, no, it wouldn't work for any steam game (it has nothing to do with steam to begin with).

Comment: @Elise I'm also getting same error. I increased availablevideomem and it showing 3000+ but still it is showing red error.